# Set first character in each word to uppercase and others to lowercase in bash 4?

Tags: bash

there is a nice feature in the bash to lowercase/uppercase:

```
$ string="A FEW WORDS"
$ echo "${string,}"
a FEW WORDS
$ echo "${string,,}"
a few words
$ echo "${string,,[AEIUO]}"
a FeW WoRDS
```

does somebody knows similiar way to set onlt 1st character in each word on a variable to uppercase and the rest to lowercase in each word?

```
$ echo "${string,,[^.]}"
a few words
$ echo "${string,,[^]}"
A FEW WORDS
$ echo "${string,,.}"
A FEW WORDS
$ echo "${string,,^.}"
A FEW WORDS
$ echo "${string,,^?}"
A FEW WORDS
$ echo "${string,,?}"
a few words
```

Comment: In general, bash parameter expansions do not nest. Using temporary variables is generally speaking the appropriate practice. `read -r -a words <<<"$string"; out_words=(); for word in "${words[@]}" ; do lcase_word=${word,,}; out_words+=( "${lcase_word^}" ); done; echo "${out_words[*]}"`

Comment: Note that the `,` operator applies its pattern to *each* character of the string separately; there's no way to match a character based on the context it appears in (for example, in this case, either at the beginning of the string or after a space).

Comment: I've never actually used (or seen anyone use) anything other than `,,`/`^^` with the implicit "match everything" pattern.

Comment: `declare -c string; string=(A fEw WoRdS); echo "${string[@]}"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A text processing tool such as GNU sed can help you here:

```
$ sed -E 's/(\w)(\w*)/\U\1\L\2/g' <<<"$string"
A Few Words
```

This captures two groups for each word (a word character, followed by zero or more word characters). The replacement uses `\U` to upper-case the first group and `\L` to lower-case the rest.

`\w` is shorthand for `[[:alnum:]_]`, i.e. anything considered to be a letter or digit in your locale, plus `_`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way

```
string="a few words"
set -- $string
string=$(echo "${@^}")
echo "$string"
```

Output

```
A Few Words
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the string into an `array` you can then use parameter expansion.

This will set the first char to uppercase:

```
strings="a few words"

arr=( $strings )

echo "${arr[@]^}"
```

Outputs:

```
A Few Words
```